# How to render 3DS keyframe animation

Tags: keyframe, 3ds

my english isn't perfect but I will try to describe my problem.

I try to render a simple animation (a block falling on the ground) from *.3ds file.

I read all information from 3ds file but the animation isn't look like propouse to have.
because the block is not reflected from the ground only in the air. As if the "track" the block is moved in the y-axis.

Maybe I used in the wrong way infromation from the 3ds file?

In my class Object3D I have Origin point read form *.3ds file but don't know how to correct used it... and I do not know whether the rotation matrix performs well, because I move an object to the point (0,0,0) performs a rotation and moves it back into his place.

Answer (score 0):

Though it might be too easy an answer, it sounds like your rendering space has Y up and the 3DS space has Z up (because of the whole "only air" thing), so you need to rotate your data to compensate for that.

On the matrix: doing rotation by temporarily changing the pivot point works.